# Real Time Calculations using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a site using bootstrap and I need to display a calculation based on options selected from two different select lists. The price displayed is dependent on the area from list number one and the number selected from list two. So for example, list one has a list of areas and list two has a list used for number of passengers. The price is driven by the Area and then the number of passengers. So if I select Blacktown then 2 it should drive a price. If I select Mt Druitt and 2, it should be a different price etc. The second part to this is that I need the price to display in a field which I have added the disabled attribute to so that customers do not type anything into the field. Hope this makes sense. Here is a snippet of the lists etc:

```html
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="img/blacktown.jpg" alt="Blacktown Councils">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <h3 id = "blacktown_councils" class = "aHeading">Blacktown Councils</h3>
                <p>Blacktown City is a local government area in western Sydney, situated on the Cumberland Plain, approximately 35 kilometres west of the Sydney central business district, in the state of New South Wales, Australia.</p>&nbsp;
    <div class = "row">
    
     <div class = "form-group">
      <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="blacktownArea">Area:</label> 
         <div class="col-md-5">
        <select class = "form-control pull-right chosen-select-deselect" id = "blacktownArea" name = "blacktownArea" data-placeholder = "Select Area" style = "border-radius: 15px;">
       <option value = ""></option>
       <option value = "Acacia Ridge">Acacia Gardens</option>
       <option value = "Arndell Park">Arndell Park</option>
       <option value = "Bidwell">Bidwell</option>
       <option value = "Blackett">Blackett</option>
       <option value = "Blacktown">Blacktown</option>
       <option value = "Bungarribee">Bungarribee</option>
       <option value = "Colebee">Colebee</option>
       <option value = "Dean Park">Dean Park</option>
       <option value = "Dharruk">Dharruk</option>
       <option value = "Doonside">Doonside</option>
       <option value = "Eastern Creek">Eastern Creek</option>
       <option value = "Emerton">Emerton</option>
       <option value = "Glendenning">Glendenning</option>
       <option value = "Glenwood">Glenwood</option>
       <option value = "Hassal Grove">Hassal Grove</option>
       <option value = "Hebersham">Hebersham</option>
       <option value = "Huntingwood">Huntingwood</option>
       <option value = "Arndell Park">Arndell Park</option>
       <option value = "Kellyville Ridge">Kellyville Ridge</option>
       <option value = "Kings Langley">Kings Langley</option>
       <option value = "Kings Park">Kings Park</option>
       <option value = "Lalor Park">Lalor Park</option>
       <option value = "Lethbridge Park">Lethbridge Park</option>
       <option value = "Marsden Park">Marsden Park</option>
       <option value = "Maryong">Maryong</option>
       <option value = "Minchinbury">Minchinbury</option>
       <option value = "Mt Druitt">Mt Druitt</option>
       <option value = "Oakhurst">Oakhurst</option>
       <option value = "Parklea">Parklea</option>
       <option value = "Plumpton">Plumpton</option>
       <option value = "Prospect">Prospect</option>
       <option value = "Quakers Hill">Quakers Hill</option>
       <option value = "Riverstone">Riverstone</option>
       <option value = "Schofields">Schofields</option>
       <option value = "Seven Hills">Seven Hills</option>
       <option value = "Shalvey">Shalvey</option>
       <option value = "Shanes Park">Shanes Park</option>
       <option value = "Stanhope Gardens">Stanhope Gardens</option>
       <option value = "The Ponds">The Ponds</option>
       <option value = "Toongabbie">Toongabbie</option>
       <option value = "Tregear">Tregear</option>
       <option value = "Vineyard">Vineyard</option>
       <option value = "Whalan">Whalan</option>
       <option value = "Willmot">Willmot</option>
       <option value = "Woodcroft">Woodcroft</option>
        </select>&nbsp;
         </div>
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="blactownPax">Passengers:</label> 
         <div class="col-md-3">
        <select class="form-control pull-right chosen-select-deselect" id="blacktownPax" name = "blacktownPax" data-placeholder = "Pax" required= "" style = "border-radius: 15px;">
       <option value = ""></option>
       <option value = "1">1</option>
       <option value = "2">2</option>
       <option value = "3">3</option>
       <option value = "4">4</option>
       <option value = "5">5</option>
       <option value = "6">6</option>
       <option value = "7">7</option>
       <option value = "8">8</option>
       <option value = "9">9</option>
       <option value = "10">10</option>
       <option value = "11">11</option>
       <option value = "12">12</option>
       <option value = "13">13</option>
       <option value = "14">14</option>
       <option value = "15">15</option>
       <option value = "16">16</option>
       <option value = "17">17</option>
       <option value = "18">18</option>
       <option value = "19">19</option>
       <option value = "20">20</option>
       <option value = "21">21</option>
       <option value = "22">22</option>
       <option value = "23">23</option>
       <option value = "24">24</option>
        </select>
         </div>
     </div>
    
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
                    <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="blacktownArea">Price:</label>
        <div class = "col-md-5">
     
         <div class="input-group pull-right">
       <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
       <input id = "dollars" type="text" class="form-control" disabled aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" style = "background-color: #fafafa;">
       <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
      </div>&nbsp;
     
     </div>
     <div class = "col-md-5">
                        <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" href="portfolio-item.html">Book Now!</i></a>
     </div>
    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I can't see your javascript. I think you need to add that. Also, you will probably have a higher chance of getting a useful answer if you created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Try to make it easy for people to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If i catch that right:
You have to get the values.
JS:

```
var val1 = document.getElementById('blacktownArea').value;
```

And after all count that and set to the correct div with something like this:

```
document.getElementById('dollars').value = your_calculation_results;
```

p.s.: just a straight guess, myabe something around this...

Comment: Thanks heaps... will try this as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use this following code:

Add this to your script section:

```
function calculate() {
var area = document.getElementById("blacktownArea").value;

var MultipleBy = 1;
switch (area) {
    case "Acacia Ridge":
        MultipleBy = 2;
        break;

}

var Pax = document.getElementById("blacktownPax").value;

var finalValue = (MultipleBy/1) * (Pax/1);
var yourInput = document.getElementById("dollars");
yourInput.value = finalValue;
}
```

add onchange = "calculate()" to both of your Select, and your done.

You will have to build your switch/case scenarios for all the different places, or replace the values in your select list to numbers that you want to multiply or whatever..

[Fiddle example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/55cwja69/2/)

Comment: glad i could help. hope u can select this as answer, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your pricing list i assumed all prices of area as 15(you can change depending on your requirement)

Now you can use onchange event on both on the both of select box and extract the selected value;

```
 <select class = "form-control pull-right chosen-select-deselect" id = "blacktownArea" name = "blacktownArea" data-placeholder = "Select Area" style = "border-radius: 15px;" onchange="myFunction()">

 <select class="form-control pull-right chosen-select-deselect" id="blacktownPax" name = "blacktownPax" data-placeholder = "Pax" required= "" style = "border-radius: 15px;" onchange="myFunction()">



<script>
          function myFunction(){
            var first=document.getElementById("blacktownArea");
            var second=document.getElementById("blacktownPax");
            var firstVal=first.options[first.selectedIndex].value;
            var secondVal=second.options[second.selectedIndex].value;

            var area=15;//you can change it according to the value of area in SecondVal
            if(firstVal!="" && secondVal!="")
            document.getElementById('dollars').value=area * secondVal;
          }
        </script>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Clcp9liY2OABqgN663KE?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much for feeding this back... I will try all three options